# Using Linq query inside List<T>.AddRange to conditionally add elements from one list to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<String>` and two `List<CustomObject>`.
I want to combine two `List<CustomObject>` but only if second `List<CustomObject>` property is not contained in `List<String>`.

So, want to do something like this:

```
resultSet1.AddRange(resultSet2.Select(x => !names.Contains(x.City)).ToList());
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are misusing `Select` when you should be using `Where`.

```
resultSet1.AddRange(resultSet2.Where(x => !names.Contains(x.City));
```

`Select` is a projection method. It takes a sequence and selects it, sometimes selecting the entire item, a single property, or projecting it into something else entirely.

`Where` is a filtering method. It takes a sequence and applies a predicate to it, yielding only the elements that pass the predicate.

(In your example, by using `Select`, you're effectively trying to add a list of `bool` to a list of `CustomObject`, which is not going to work.)

---

Not addressing the specific error at hand, here are some additional ideas to consider.

This is a situation where a `HashSet<string>` might be beneficial for `names`, particularly if `names` is significantly large. `Contains` on a `HashSet<T>` is of O(1) complexity, whereas it is O(n) for `List<T>`. However, there is overhead associated with the HashSet, so if you have any concerns, it's best to measure both and see which is more performant.

One more thing that might help, if you simply need to stream one sequence after the other and do not necessarily need to change or add to either collection, you might consider using `Union` or `Concat` operations.

```
var sequence = resultSet1.Union(resultSet2.Where(x => !names.Contains(x.City)));
var sequence = resultSet1.Concat(resultSet2.Where(x => !names.Contains(x.City)));
```

The difference in the two being that `Union` will filter out any duplicates in the resulting sequence (from both inputs, not just the second against the first), `Concat` applies no duplicate-filtering logic and simply streams one sequence after the other. The input sequences (`resultSet1` and `resultSet2`) are unmodified.